# Botão para adicionar um novo form e um novo campo AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Preciso fazer um formulário de perguntas e respostas, basicamente, da seguinte forma:

- Deve permitir adicionar várias perguntas, cada qual com no mínimo 2 respostas, onde uma delas deve ser marcada como correta;
- Excluir respostas e perguntas, ao excluir uma pergunta as respostas devem ser excluídas.
- Permitir editar tanto as perguntas como as respostas a qualquer instante;

Eu pensei em fazer da seguinte forma: Quando o usuário quiser adicionar uma nova pergunta, terá um botão que quando ele clique, adiciona um novo form, e ali, seja criada a pergunta e as respostas. E dentro do form, ao lado do input, um outro botao que quando clicado, adiciona uma nova opção de resposta.

Preciso fazer com Angular. Gostaria de saber como faço esse esquema dos botões

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: E o que você tentou até agora? Algum código pra compartilhar?